# how to get previously selected element in an svg on "mousedown" event?

Tags: javascript, svg, mousedown

I am trying to create nodes (that are rectangles in svg) that has "mousedown" events. They all have text contents that I print out somewhere else on the webpage when I click on a node.

But you can't see visually which node is selected. I managed to change the color of the stroke when I click on a rectangle, but when I click on another rectangle the previously selected one will have the same color.

I'm using this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < g_items.length; i++){
    g_items[i].addEventListener("mousedown", // OR click
        function(evt){
            evt.target.setAttribute("style", "#ffffff");

            generate_html(evt.target.parentNode.textContent);

    });
```

Note that I don't actually use the "setAttribute" function like this because the actual code has a lots of junk to be presented here.

Also I tried playing with "evt.timeStamp" but I couldn't make it work.

So basically what I want:

- Clicking on a node changes the stroke color to white of the rectangle
- Clicking on another node replaces the previously selected node stroke color back to black

Comment: Each time a click happens, can you set all the nodes to black and then just set the currently clicked node to white? If not, I think you'll need to use some sort of stack or global variable to keep track of the previously selected node.

Comment: easier with CSS classes than colours. On click assign a class to a node and remove the class from the previously selected node. Keep the currently selected node in a global.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work. inspecting the elements shows the correct color but the outline is not visible at all. For testing purposes I set he color there to red. base color is black and the selection color is white. It behaves the same visually. :/ great tip tho.

Comment: Thats the problem. I don't know how to tag the previously selected node. As I said the problem is not with the coloring. It is with selecting or tagging or somehow know anything about the previously selected node.

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to tag the Child not the parent with the coloring. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final solution was by @Calvin Belden. Thank you for it!

```
for(var i = 0; i < g_items.length; i++){
    g_items[i].addEventListener("mousedown", // OR click
        function(evt){
            for(var j = 0; j < g_items.length; j++){

                var style_split = g_items[j].firstElementChild.getAttribute("style").split(/stroke:#ffffff;|stroke:#000000;/);

                g_items[j].firstElementChild.setAttribute("style", style_split[0] + "stroke:#000000;" + style_split[1]);    
            }

            var style_split = evt.target.getAttribute("style").split(/stroke:#ffffff;|stroke:#000000;/);

            evt.target.setAttribute("style", style_split[0] + "stroke:#ffffff;" + style_split[1]);

            generate_html(evt.target.parentNode.textContent);
    });
}
```

The other problem was that I couldn't exactly use css for setting values because I loaded an SVG from Inkscape that creates a long style attribute to every element where I couldn't overwrite only 1 element of the style.

here is the attribute:

```
"opacity:1;fill:#a7a7a7;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
```